# java generics: Bound mismatch for string

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, abstract-class

my code is as below, and I got the error message `Bound Mismatch Error: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <K extends myComparable<K>> of the type myInterface<K,V>`:

```
interface myComparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}

interface myInterface<K extends myComparable<K>, V> {  
}

public class myClass implements myInterface<String,String>{          
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }    
}
```

However, if I changed `K extends myComparable<K>` to `K extends Comparable<K>` (without changing the first line; i.e. to use `Comparable` instead of `myComparable`), the error will be solved.

Why? And how can I use my own `myComparable`?

Comment: _And how can I use my own myComparable?_ To do what? Obviously, the standard `java.lang.String` class is not a subclass of your custom `myComparable` type. What do you actually want to happen?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just want to know how `Comparable` works. Now I based on your hint, and I got a solution as below.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution (i.e. to use `myString` instead of `String`):

```
interface myComparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}

interface myInterface<K extends myComparable<K>, V> {
}

class myString implements myComparable<myString>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(myString o) {
        return 0;
    }   
}

public class myClass implements myInterface<myString,myString>{      
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `implements myInterface<String, String>`, you're 'binding' the `K` type variable to `String` and the V type variable to `String`.

The declaration of the K type variable in particular has a bound on it: You've declared it as `myInterface<K extends myComparable<K>, V>` which means that any bound you pick for `K` must at least 'fit' this restriction.

And it doesn't, which is why the compiler won't let you.

The `java.lang.String` class actually implements `Comparable<String>` - it's right there in the javadoc as well as the source if you care to look; you can also just cast it:

```
Comparable<String> test = "hello"; // this compiles and runs fine.
```

The reason is that string was written by sun/oracle as: `public final class String implements Comparable<String>`.

It was not written with `implements myComparable<String>`.

**It is not possible to make java.lang.String implement your interface**.

That is not how interfaces work; java is nominally and not structurally typed: You can't decree that all Strings are myComparables, just because they so happen to have a `compareTo` method.

Imagine it worked that way and I wrote this class:

```
public class Gun {
    public void shoot(Person person) { ... }
}
```

quite a dangerous class!

Let's say it worked the way you appear things are. Then I could do:

```
public interface Camera {
    public void shoot(Person p);
}

Camera c = new Gun();
c.shoot(somebody);
```

and good grief, now we have an extremely dangerous situation going on. Fortunately, java **does not** work this way; A Gun is not a Camera. Eventhough it so happens to have all the methods that the Camera interface declared.

You can make your own types that implement your own interfaces, of course. That's no problem. However, in general, it doesn't seem useful to make an interface named `myComparable`.